# integration SQL to a web service in Java

Tags: java, mysql, web, service

I created a simple web service. Well now that's done, I have to complicate things: connect to a MySQL database and communicate with it via the web service! 
I can not find on the internet how to make this connection to my web service (I know very well do so when there is no web service and it is a simple Java application). But the problem that in web service I don't have a `main`, just methods.

That's a part of my code:

```
package impression;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "impression")
public class impression {




@WebMethod(operationName = "EnvoiMessage")
public String messageReception(@WebParam(name = "msg") String msg) {
msg="Demande recu!";
return msg;
}   

/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "affichageDemande")
@Oneway
public void affichageDemande() {


//here i want to display the table created im my database

}   
}
```

I will be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this thread. [EJB3: How to inject DataSource in EJB3 during Junit testing as raw POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294887/ejb3-how-to-inject-datasource-in-ejb3-during-junit-testing-as-raw-pojo)

That is what you need. An injected datasource, then you can do as you do in "regular java with a main method" :-).

Good luck